# How to send pcsc commands to SAM and not to card on reader

Tags: python, mifare, pcsc

I have acr1281 reader with SAM slot (secure access module).
I can communicate with card by pc/sc using python library [smartcard](https://pyscard.sourceforge.io/user-guide.html).
But I want to send commands to the SAM inserted to the reader.

How to 'switch commands channel' for that, is it even possible?
smartcard library can send control command to reader (PC_to_RDR_Escape) but in the acr1281 documentation specified only GetFirmvareVersion command.

I even can see that SAM inserted or not - I call SCardStatus() and with SAM inserted get 0x34 code (as I understand this is `SCARD_POWERED=0x10 | SCARD_NEGOTIABLE=0x20 | SCARD_PRESENT=0x04`), and without SAM it is 0x0c = `SCARD_SWALLOWED=0x08 | SCARD_PRESENT=0x04`.

But all the commands I send go to MIFARE PICC placed on reader. And I want to send commands to SAM inserted into the reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ubuntu Linux with pscs driver installed I have 3 readers in `smartcard` library:

```
from smartcard.System import readers
print(readers())
```

- ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader 00 00
- ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader 00 01
- ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader 00 02

Reader `00 00` is inactive for me, I think it's for contact cards,
reader `00 01` is for PICC (MIFARE in my case),
reader `00 02` is for SAM slot in ACR,

So I use reader `01` to send card APDU and reader `02` to send commands to SAM and successfully solved my task.

Not sure how to find them automatically but I think that this `00 00` and so on is constants in names and I can select readers for PICC and for SAM  by last symbol in their names.

I connect to PICC reader just by `smartcard.CardRequest.CardRequest()` - waiting for card in proximity. 
So I have to find only SAM reader and connect to it:

```
sam_connection = readers()[2].createConnection()
sam_connection.connect(mode=SCARD_SHARE_SHARED,
                        disposition=SCARD_LEAVE_CARD,
                        protocol=SCARD_PROTOCOL_ANY)
```